# SCALA PAttern matching with recursive in LIST

Tags: scala

How to print the element of list after every function call in recursive function?

```
 def multiply(list: List[Int]): Unit =list match {
        case Nil => 1
        case n :: rest => n * multiply(rest)
    }
```

each time multiply() is called , I want to see the element of list it is going to process.

Comment: Homework?

`println(n)`

Comment: Call `print` after every iteration.

Comment: where should i call print because i tried inside function then it is giving error, could u share the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should return an `Int` instead of `Unit`.  To print elements iteratively, just insert a `println` underneath `case head :: tail`:

```
def multiply(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
    case Nil => 1
    case n :: rest =>
      println(n)
      n * multiply(rest)
  }

multiply(List(1,2,3,4))
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// res1: Int = 24
```

Comment: got def multiply(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
    case Nil => 1
    case n :: rest =>
      println(list)
      n * multiply(rest)
  }