# Ad hoc function in scala to concatenate two lists recursively: No use of "concat"

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I want to have a function in Scala that concatenate two lists without using the built-in functions of that purpose. It should be written in a functional recursive way but I am not sure where to start.

```
def concatList(lleft: List[String], lright: List[String]): List[String] {

  }
```

Comment: Start with the signature of your function.

Comment: The **Discord** server would be a better place to ask that question.

Comment: If you had to concatenate two lists manually one item at a time, how would you proceed?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Updated

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am not aware of the Discord server you are talking about

Comment: @GaëlJ, add the first item from the second list at the end of the first list, and so on with the rest of the second list

Comment: @Usr654789 https://discord.gg/Eswfshby https://users.scala-lang.org/t/can-we-have-an-official-scala-discord-server/5157

Comment: @Usr654789 great, sounds like a good approach for a recursive method then. Just write that with code :)

Comment: @Usr654789 Now use pattern matching for one of arguments. The argument can be either empty list or a list consisting head and tail.

Comment: @Usr654789 https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Thank you all, I will try what you all suggested!

Comment: @Usr654789 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216322 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you solved your homework question by now. For anyone stumbling on this in the future, you can use tail recursion like this

```
def concatList(lleft: List[String], lright: List[String]): List[String] = lright match {
  case Nil => lleft  // base condition
  case head :: tail =>  // add first element to end of lleft and recurse
    concatList(lleft :+ head, tail)
}
```

Comment: Why is the 3rd case for?

Comment: @DmytroMitin edge case if a user passes `null` for the second argument. It would yield a nasty `MatchError` otherwise.

Comment: If you start to handle nulls, what will be when `lleft` is `null` and `lright` is `head :: tail`? NPE is not better than MatchError. I guess if nulls are possible then it's better to have `Option[List[String]]` and handle this with `Option.apply(..)`.

Comment: I did this way last night on some Discord channel, They advised to use ::: , it is still faster, but without the the third case

Comment: @DmytroMitin I removed it.